# Store image to Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

Before adding image to `JLabel`, I used below code to resize them.

```
BufferedImage myPicture1 = ImageIO.read(new
File("C:\\Users\\yumi\\Desktop\\Salad.png"));
Image scaled1 = myPicture1.getScaledInstance(80,95,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
JLabel picLabel1 = new JLabel("Japanese Noodles",new 
ImageIcon(scaled1),JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(picLabel1);
```

Now I have array, want to store image to array

```
static private JLabel[] foodLabel;
static private JTextField[] qtyField;
static private ImageIcon[] imageIcon;
static private Image[] imageScaled;
static private BufferedImage[] image;
static private File[] file;
private static final int ELEMENTS = 9;
```

Trying to read file and scale it

```
file[0] = new File("C:\\Users\\yumi\\Desktop\\Salad.png");
         .....

for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        image[i] = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
        imageScaled[i] = image[i].getScaledInstance(80,95,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        foodLabel[i] = new JLabel(imageIcon([imageScaled[i]])); // error
}
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Comment: what is `imageIcon([imageScaled[i]])` supposed to do? `imageIcon` is an array - `(` makes no sense here, but `[` would not make sense as well since you cannot access an array with an `Image` as key.

Comment: What are the correct way to do ? I want to put the scaled image to `foodLabel[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. You have to create an `ImageIcon` for your scaled image first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    image[i] = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
    imageScaled[i] = image[i].getScaledInstance(80,95,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    imageIcon[i] = new ImageIcon(imageScaled[i]);
    foodLabel[i] = new JLabel(imageIcon[i]);
}
```

Note that there seems to be no reason to keep all those values in an array. Unless you have more code that references those arrays the following is a bit cleaner:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
    Image imageScaled = image.getScaledInstance(80,95,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageScaled);
    foodLabel[i] = new JLabel(imageIcon);
}
```